# Can chronic muscle strain/tension persist after its causes are removed?

Tags: muscle, stress

Bad posture, stress, lack of sleep, weak muscles/imbalances, and other factors are often cited as causes for chronic muscle tension. Is the ongoing presence of such tension an indication that at least one of these causes has not been addressed yet?

I'm trying to understand whether, given enough time (e.g. years), the contraction of some muscles over longer stretches of time can become a habit even after the initial cause is not present anymore.

It might not be exactly the same but people who grind their teeth, bite their fingernails, or experience migraines related to muscle strain, are often told that stress could be the cause of such issues. Is it possible that these habits remain long after that initial cause (e.g. stress) has been addressed and is gone?

Bonus points for a recommendation of a good (scientifically sound) book on the topic of muscles, tension, causes, and treatment.

**Edit:** Changed some words for better clarity.

Comment: "...permanent contraction can become a habit..." Do you mean the other way around? Permanent means permanent; habit has nothing to do with it. "Is it possible that these habits remain long after that initial cause (e.g. stress) has been addressed and is gone?" This has everything to do with habit.

Comment: The word "permanent" can be confusing, I admit. What I meant was "over longer stretches of time". I'm asking whether muscle strain/tension can take on a life of its own at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not only *can* happen, it actually *will* happen eventually, as every physiotherapist will be able to tell you. That's why moving joints (and, accordingly, the attached muscles) through their range of motion on a regular basis (ideally several times a day) is important for the sustainment of MSK health.

As [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/030698779190233O) muses, there are mechanisms that make that muscles which strain statically (isometrical muscle tension) over longer periods of time will become more sensitive against stretching them. That, in turn, means that they will tense up even more with even the slightest elongation trying to prevent further stretching, which leads to pathological states like the [frozen shoulder](https://www.nhsinform.scot/illnesses-and-conditions/muscle-bone-and-joints/conditions/frozen-shoulder).

Stress is a contributor since it increases sympathetic neural activity in the vegetative system, which in turn globally increases muscle tension.

Another factor is that the [connective tissue adapts to the state](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306987705004305) so that the contractile elements in there and possible ischaemia due to the vascularisation worsening further perpetuate the state.

Regarding a good book it is a bit problematic. The scientifically sound books are mostly the more general teaching books like [this one](https://shop.thieme.de/Functional-Anatomy-for-Physical-Therapists/9783131768711). The more specific ones tend to either be coloured by the theoretical and/or methodological biases of the authors or are of questionable scientific value in the first place. [This one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-25682-1) might be a good compromise but I cannot vouch for it. A problem here is that physiotherapy as a science of moving muscles and other structures in a living organism is a comparatively young science. The classical medical and sports sciences derived most outcomes regarding those structures from post mortem experiments or - let's face it - biomechanically based speculation. Therefore, we simply have to admit that there are many things we do not really *know* as of yet.

Generally, you'll need some training in medical professions to be able to follow any scientific writing on the issue. There are no easy answers, and medical advice and treatment will always have to be tailored to the specific person by a medical professional.

Comment: This is more than what I was hoping for. Thank you so much and greetings from P'berg!